Karabiner: Unable to turn on caps lock since recent update
I normally remap the caps lock key to control using MacOS System settings. This has worked well. However, sometimes I need to use actual caps lock, and I've used Karabiner to make a double tap on the left shift key activate caps lock. This has worked well. However, recently this stopped working and I suspect it is due to some driver update that Karabiner informed me about.
I've now tried a number of different ways to activate caps lock using complex modifications. What baffles me is that Karbiner Event Viewer displays caps_lock events when my modifications are activated, but the system does not recognise them; the caps_lock has no effect.
Right now I've set right command + c to send caps_lock:
 {
  "description": "Change right_command + c to Caps lock",
    "manipulators": [
      {
        "from": {
           "key_code": "c",
           "modifiers": {
           "mandatory": ["right_command"],
           "optional": ["any"]
         }
       },
         "to": [{ "key_code": "caps_lock" }],
         "type": "basic"
       }
    ]
 },

Here's a screenshot of the events captured by Karabiner Event Viewer:

I've also imported a modification to disable the "accidental caps lock press" that MacOS implements, but there seems to be no difference.
Anyone else with similar problems using Karabiner?
